# Проблема в функции main() при парсинге

Tags: python, парсер, selenium

Вот мой код

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium.webdriver import FirefoxProfile
from selenium import webdriver
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import time
user=UserAgent()
profile=webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('general.useragent.override',user.random)
driver=webdriver.Firefox(profile)
driver.get('https://rabota.ykt.ru/') 

#Это смена юзер агента


def rabota(table):
    soup=BeatifulSoup(table,'lxml')
    vacansii=soup.findAll(class_='class="r-vacancy_list_item ng-scope')
    for vacansia in vacansii:
        knopka=vacansia.find(class_='r-vacancy_title').text
        print(knopka)
def main():

    table=driver.find_by_css_selector('ul.r-vacancy_list').get_attribute('innerHTML')
if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

В парсинге недавно и поэтому не знаю. Я понимаю, что там не совместимость селениума и супа, но я тренируюсь использовать селениум. Мне надо найти селениумом таблицу и передать ей супу.

Вот код ошибки

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python\rabota\parser.py", line 27, in <module>
    main()
  File "E:\Python\rabota\parser.py", line 25, in main
    table=driver.find_by_css_selector('ul.r-vacancy_list').get_attribute('innerHTML')
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_by_css_selector'
```

Что сделать, чтобы заработало?

Comment: Нет такого метода как `'find_by_css_selector'`. Должен быть этот `find_element_by_css_selector`.

Comment: Блин, затупил. Спасибо!